# In an ASP.NET Web Setup Project, can I disable anonymous access in IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, installation

I have a really simple ASP.NET web application and a web setup project that deploys the project output and content files to a virtual directory in IIS.

What I want is for the MSI to automatically disable Anonymouse Access for that virtual folder in IIS.

I suspect it can probably be done by writing some code in a custom action DLL, that would be acceptable, but is there any way to do it within the the settings of the web setup project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Taken from technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/guidance/identitymanagement/idmanage/P3ASPD_6.mspx?mfr=true)

> The property for anonymous access is
>   unfortunately not available through
>   Web setup projects. For this reason,
>   you must:
>
> 1. Write a custom installer to enable or disable anonymous access.
> 2. Pass the necessary parameters from the setup wizard to the installer at
>      run time.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you know that you could disallow users who are not authenticated via `web.config`

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/> 
</authorization>
</system.web>
```

would do it I think.

Comment: This is not the same as disabling anonymous access entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="SignIn.aspx" defaultUrl="Welcome.aspx"  protection="All">
          <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
            <user name="lee" password="lee12345"/>
            <user name="add" password="add12345"/>
          </credentials>
        </forms>
      </authentication>

        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />     //deny acces to anonymous users
        </authorization>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```